# SharePoint image list item how to display in SSRS report using Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services

Creating SSRS report using SharePoint site as a data source how to display SharePoint list image item  URL in SSRS Report display image.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.If the Sharepoint list item is picture/hyperlink and single text column type then only  image rending into ssrs report generation.using external data option.